# DocuSign REST API - node.js Signer does not respect agentCanEditEmail and agentCanEditName attributes

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I have written a node.js app to interface with the DocuSign API. The goal is to have an agent receive documents to approve (including editing Signer name/email) before sending it along to the customer to sign (Signer).

Expected behavior:

- We expect to be able to pass email and name for the Signer and then allow the Agent to edit these fields before approving. This is how DocuSign behaves when the template is set up on their website (no API).

Actual behavior:

- If all Signers have email and name pre-filled, the Agent auto-approves when clicking the DocuSign link and the envelope is automatically sent along to the Signer
- If name and/or email is missing from a signer, the Agent then has to fill out the missing fields before approving.

According to the [agent documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/#agent-recipient), we should be able to set agentCanEditEmail and agentCanEditName on the Signer model. Through experimentation, these two fields seem to have no effect on the outcome. I have tried setting them equal to the Boolean true (more logical) as well as the String "true" (what the documentation hints at). I have also tried using designatorId and a few other fields which seemed relevant to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Everything else works as expected ... relevant code

```
let agent1 = docusign.Agent.constructFromObject({
    email: args.agentEmail,
    name: args.agentName,
    recipientId: '1',
    routingOrder: '1'
});
let signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
    email: args.signerEmail,
    name: args.signerName,
    recipientId: '10',
    routingOrder: '10',
    agentCanEditEmail: 'true',
    agentCanEditName: 'true',
    roleName: 'Signer'
});
env.recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
    agents: [agent1],
    signers: [signer1]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there are two types of recipients that can update other recipients:

[Agent](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/#agent-recipient) and [Intermediary](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/#intermediary-recipient)

The difference is one is used for cases where there is something already and they may or may not change it. The other is used to specify them and are part of the workflow. They must specify them or this envelope will never continue to route.

when you used the web app and it worked ok, the last recipient (your 'signer' '10' one) did you specify their email and name or just left it as an open role?

I suspect you did the former, so you cannot use an agent. You need to use an intermediary. The web app would actually give you an error if you use an agent in that case, but maybe the API doesn't enforce it (not sure about that).

Bottom line - change to an **intermediary** and I think that would solve your issue.

Comment: thank you for your response!

using the web app, agents worked as i anticipated - meaning i was able to specify signer name and email and still require the agent to approve/correct

changing to an intermediary almost worked ... now the two (signer and intermediary) are emailed simultaneously :(

Comment: you would need to set a different routing order to avoid that.

Comment: how so? could you please provide an example routing order?

Comment: do you have routingOrder=1, routingOrder=2 etc. in your request/code? Please paste your request here and I can fix the routing order for you.